Strapi crash while trying to create Gallery
I am following quick start guide and installation runs correctly. I can access admin panel, everything seems working. I am able to crate new "Collection type". However whenever I try to create "Component" it crash and I receive the error below.
*⠸ Loading Strapi[ERROR]  There seems to be an unexpected error, try again with --debug for more information

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type          ││   
string. Received undefined                                                     ││   
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)                                  ││   
at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)                            ││   
at Object.join (node:path:429:7)                                               ││   
at D:\code\strapi\strapi\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\dist\core\loaders\compo   ││   nents.js:17:31                                                                 ││   
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)                                                 ││   
at D:\code\strapi\strapi\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\dist\core\loaders\compo   ││   nents.js:14:32                                                                 ││   
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)                                                  ││   
at Object.loadComponents (D:\code\strapi\strapi\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\   ││   dist\core\loaders\components.js:13:27)                                         ││   
at async Strapi.loadComponents                                                 ││   (D:\code\strapi\strapi\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\dist\Strapi.js:320:23)      ││   
at async Promise.all (index 6)*

package.json as below
{
  "name": "strapi",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi",
    "deploy": "strapi deploy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.25.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.25.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.25.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-cloud": "4.25.3",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.6.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.4",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "abfd60a1-e7e4-4976-a053-f5fa30602141"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0 <=20.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}

Tried to delete node_modules and install packages didn't work.
I also delete folder and created new ones, but this also didn't work.

i have got the same issue yesterday when creating a new component on 4.25.3 version of strapi : After the creation, strapi loading fails and a new launch fails (with npm run dev) too.
As you will find here, it seems to be related in my case to my this version and my OS being windows, i just downgrade to 4.25.2 and it worked like a charm : https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/20730#issuecomment-2226220191
